# How to write a SQL query on a table with nested record?

Tags: mysql, sql, types, nested, record

I want to know what is the top fruit on 2021-08-15 (completed with highest total price), table below:

**product**

```
------------------
id | name
------------------
1  | banana
2  | orange
3  | apple
4  | watermelon
5  | pineapple
```

**sales**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
s_id | sn.id | sn.product_id | sn.status | sn.total_price | created_at
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    | 1     | 2             | BOOKED    | 300            | 2021-08-15 12:20:32
     | 2     | 5             | COMPLETED | 800            |
     | 3     | 5             | COMPLETED | 200            |
2    | 4     | 2             | COMPLETED | 500            | 2021-08-16 09:00:59
     | 5     | 1             | CANCELLED | 1000           |
```

How to write a query on a table with nested records?
Does MySQL even have nested record data type?

Comment: MySQL does not really have a "nested record data type".  It does support JSON, but that seems like overkill.  Your `sales` table looks malformed.

Comment: How are the tables connected? What I imagine id is the `PRIMARY KEY` of product, but what is the `FOREIGN KEY` on the sales table?

Comment: Can you also shared what query you tried already, what is the result you are getting and what is the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from
  (select p.id,p.name,sum(s.total_price) as sumOfSales
  from product p join sales s on p.id = s.product_id 
  where s.status = "COMPLETED"
  group by p.id,p.name) T
order by sumOfSales desc
```

Comment: So, when dealing with tables with nested record, it's pretty much the same like usual? What about WHERE s.status = "COMPLETED" <- should it be like this, or WHERE s.sn.status = "COMPLETED"?

Comment: So what is the name of the column? If it is sn.status you must use it. It depends on the structure of your data.